# Except function in dataframe spark scala parameters and implementation.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, except

I see that `except` and `not in` are same in sql but spark we have "except" function .

[The documentation is there [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#except(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)) but can anyone give example for how to implement this in **scala** .

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the `DataFrame` class does contain the word 'sql', but it's still a class that you can create and use directly in scala.  You can call the `except` function:

```
df_final = df1.except(df2)
```